# lgb.train ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lightgbm

I want to train the lightgbm model as follows:

```
train = pd.read_csv(path + "all_train.csv")

# last 8 days for online predictions
# left days for offline train&valid dataset
online_pred = get_windows(train, 541, 548+1)
offline_train = get_windows(train, 0, 541-7)
offline_valid = get_windows(train, 541-7, 541)

cate_feat = train.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).columns

features = [c for c in train.columns if #(c not in cate_feat) & 
            (c not in ['pv', 'uv'])
           ]

train_x = offline_train[features]
train_y = offline_train['pv']

valid_x = offline_valid[features]
valid_y = offline_valid['pv']

for it in cate_feat:
    train_x.loc[:,it] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(train_x[it].astype(str))
    valid_x.loc[:,it] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(valid_x[it].astype(str))

print(train_x.head())
print(valid_x.head())

del offline_train, offline_valid
import gc
gc.collect()
from time import sleep
sleep(30)

for it in cate_feat:
    train_x = train_x.astype('category')

    valid_x = train_y.astype('category')



trn_data = lgb.Dataset(train_x.values, label=train_y.values)
val_data = lgb.Dataset(valid_x.values, label=valid_y.values)

del train_x, train_y, valid_x, valid_y, train
gc.collect()
sleep(30)
pv_predict = np.zeros((online_pred.shape[0], ))

clf = lgb.train(params, trn_data, 10000, valid_sets=[trn_data, val_data], verbose_eval=100, early_stopping_rounds=500, 
                categorical_feature=cate_feat,
                feval=cita_score, evals_result=None
               )

pred = lgb.pred
```

And here is the `train` `DataFrame`:

```
print(train.head())

   time      event_type  pv   uv   distinct_id          browser  \
0  20181101  $pageview  6549  674 -8539420110265898132     NaN   
1  20181101  $pageview  6549  674 -1032985922238039245  Chrome   
2  20181101  $pageview  6549  674 -1032985922238039245  Chrome   
3  20181101  $pageview  6549  674 -1032985922238039245  Chrome   
4  20181101  $pageview  6549  674 -1046230289121081999     NaN   

  browser_version  is_first_day  is_login lib lib_version       os os_version  \
0             NaN           1.0         0  JS     4.1.0.3      NaN        NaN   
1    70.0.3538.77           1.0         0  JS     4.1.0.3  Windows         10   
2    70.0.3538.77           1.0         0  JS     4.1.0.3  Windows         10   
3    70.0.3538.77           1.0         0  JS     4.1.0.3  Windows         10   
4             NaN           1.0         0  JS     4.1.0.3      NaN        NaN   

  platform  screen_height  screen_width     title  \
0       JS         1024.0        1024.0     demo   
1       JS         1080.0        1920.0     register   
2       JS         1080.0        1920.0     demo   
3       JS         1080.0        1920.0     register      
4       JS         1600.0        1600.0     private deploy   

                                                 url      country  province city  \
0  https://ark.analysys.cn/portal/industry-demo.html      China       PK    PK   
1  https://ark.analysys.cn/view/sign/signup.html?...      China       PK    PK   
2  https://ark.analysys.cn/portal/industry-demo.html      China       SH    SH   
3  https://ark.analysys.cn/view/sign/signup.html?...      China       SH    SH   
4  https://ark.analysys.cn/portal/access-private....      China       PK    PK   

                                            referrer     is_first_time model  \
0                                                NaN            NaN    NaN   
1  https://ark.analysys.cn/?utm_campaign=%E6%96%B...            NaN    NaN   
2  https://ark.analysys.cn/?utm_campaign=%E6%96%B...            NaN    NaN   
3  https://ark.analysys.cn/portal/industry-demo.html            NaN    NaN   
4                                                NaN            NaN    NaN   

  brand utm_campaign utm_content utm_medium utm_source utm_term  \
0   NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN      NaN   
1   NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN      NaN   
2   NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN      NaN   
3   NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN      NaN   
4   NaN          NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN      NaN   

  utm_campaign_id  startup_time time_zone  web_crawler traffic_source_type  \
0             NaN  1.540976e+12       NaN          NaN                 NaN   
1             NaN  1.541053e+12       NaN          NaN                 NaN   
2             NaN  1.541053e+12       NaN          NaN                 NaN   
3             NaN  1.541053e+12       NaN          NaN                 NaN   
4             NaN  1.541018e+12       NaN          NaN                 NaN   

   search_engine social_share_from referrer_domain  social  scene  \
0            NaN               NaN             NaN     NaN    NaN   
1            NaN               NaN             NaN     NaN    NaN   
2            NaN               NaN             NaN     NaN    NaN   
3            NaN               NaN             NaN     NaN    NaN   
4            NaN               NaN             NaN     NaN    NaN   

  search_keyword  scene_type  channel language session_id  social_media  \
0            NaN         NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN           NaN   
1            NaN         NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN           NaN   
2            NaN         NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN           NaN   
3            NaN         NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN           NaN   
4            NaN         NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN           NaN   

   signup_time url_domain  is_time_calibrated  click_x  click_y device_type  \
0          NaN        NaN                 NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN   
1          NaN        NaN                 NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN   
2          NaN        NaN                 NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN   
3          NaN        NaN                 NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN   
4          NaN        NaN                 NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN   

   element_path  page_height  page_width  event_duration  viewport_height  \
0           NaN          NaN         NaN             NaN              NaN   
1           NaN          NaN         NaN             NaN              NaN   
2           NaN          NaN         NaN             NaN              NaN   
3           NaN          NaN         NaN             NaN              NaN   
4           NaN          NaN         NaN             NaN              NaN   

   viewport_position  viewport_width  campaign_shortlink  pagename  nav_name  \
0                NaN             NaN                 NaN       NaN       NaN   
1                NaN             NaN                 NaN       NaN       NaN   
2                NaN             NaN                 NaN       NaN       NaN   
3                NaN             NaN                 NaN       NaN       NaN   
4                NaN             NaN                 NaN       NaN       NaN   

   referrer_demo  board_name  click_position datafrom  day  
0            NaN         NaN             NaN      NaN    0  
1            NaN         NaN             NaN      NaN    0  
2            NaN         NaN             NaN      NaN    0  
3            NaN         NaN             NaN      NaN    0  
4            NaN         NaN             NaN      NaN    0
```

When I try to use `lgb.train` to train model, I get error:

> ```
>  41 clf = lgb.train(params, trn_data, 10000, valid_sets=[trn_data, val_data], verbose_eval=100, early_stopping_rounds=500, 
>  42                 categorical_feature=cate_feat,
> ```
>
> ---> 43                 feval=cita_score, evals_result=None
>        44                )
>        45
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py in
>   train(params, train_set, num_boost_round, valid_sets, valid_names,
>   fobj, feval, init_model, feature_name, categorical_feature,
>   early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates,
>   keep_training_booster, callbacks)
>       140              ._set_predictor(predictor) \
>       141              .set_feature_name(feature_name) \
>   --> 142              .set_categorical_feature(categorical_feature)
>       143 
>       144     is_valid_contain_train = False
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in
>   set_categorical_feature(self, categorical_feature)    1196
>   Dataset with set categorical features.    1197         """
>   -> 1198         if self.categorical_feature == categorical_feature:    1199             return self    1200         if self.data is not None:
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I have searched some related questions and I find some of them get such errors because of `numpy.ndarray` problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous).
But I think I didn't find similar problems here.
So could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the thing that causes the error to be raised.

> ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py
>
> ```
> 1200 |    if self.data is not None:
> ```

Look at the reference [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html). `lightgbm.train()` method expects 'train' parameter to be a `lightgbm.Dataset` for which you can find the documentation [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html#lightgbm.Dataset).

So you need to create a `lightgbm.Dataset` object for your datasets. You can do it as follows:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
...
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(data=X_train, label=y_train)
```

Then, you can train your model without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
cate_feat = train.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).columns
```

This creates a `numpy` array base type for `cate_feat` which expects a list according to the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html).  Problem is an array does boolean calculations element-wise:

```
np.array([1,2]) == np.array([1,2])
np.array([True, True])
```

Which the `if` statement can't parse (it's looking for a single boolean).

Meanwhile lists compare the whole

```
[1,2] == [1,2]
True
```

So the `if` statement works.

The solution should be to turn that initial line into

```
cate_feat = list(train.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).columns)
```

I *think* everything else should work after that.

Comment: I have tried it as you suggest. But it doesn't fix problems. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First 1 couldn't understand the logic of writing this twice.

```
for it in cate_feat:
    train_x = train_x.astype('category')

    valid_x = train_y.astype('category')


for it in cate_feat:
    train_x.loc[:,it] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(train_x[it].astype(str))
    valid_x.loc[:,it] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(valid_x[it].astype(str))
```

you aren't even using the iterator anywhere in the loop in the first case.

2nd, this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) might be able to help.
Read the Accepted answer and try to implement it in the context of your problem.